# "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" error without using quit method

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I had little problem with my project which is driven by selenium.I have made a minimal repro to reproduce my problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os

class Account:
    def __init__(self,client):
        self.client = client
        self.foo()

    def foo(self):
        self.client.get("https://google.com")

class User:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id

    def search(self,account):
        account.client.get("https://wwww.google.com")


client = webdriver.PhantomJS()
a = Account(client)
a.foo()

while True:
    someid = input("Input id : ")
    u = User(someid)
    u.search(a)
    while True:
        try:
            u.search(a)
            os.system("cls")
            print("Started.... press ctrl+c to stop")
            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
    if input("Search more? (y/n)").lower() == "n":
        break
```

The error :

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

is been thrown in the second iteration of first while (when i stops inside loop and allow continuation of first loop)